# Dia pdf export (windows)

Tags: pdf, export, dia

I have created some flowcharts in Dia (diaw.exe 0.97.2 - Windows 7 64 bit).
Now I want to export them to pdf.

This is working alright if I use File > Page Setup > Fit to...
Problem is, Diagrams with different sizes all get zoomed differently.

My perfect scale would be 41, but when I use that, I just get a bunch of empty pages when I export them to pdf.
What "works" is if I draw a rectangle around the whole page in dia and set the line color to white, so it is not displayed. Still, the pdfs contain 3 empty pages and on the 4th page is my flowchart.

I didnt find a dia-related forum, so I hope somebody here can help me out.
It "seems" to be just because of the Page setup...

Thanks a lot,
basti

Answer (score 2):

Page setup is exactly why this happens. If you didn't make any changes to your dia setup, your grid consists of grey lines and blue lines. The blue lines mark borders of a page. If you want everything to fit on one page, you have to enlarge your page until everything fits into one page.

Comment: Thank You for Your answer. I think I have to rephrase my question:
Why does it behave like that? What is the intention of the programmers to make it behave like that?

My issue is that I made a lot of different diagrams with same-sized boxes to make the formatting consistent. Then I realized I didn't have enough space in one of them, but if I scaled all of them a bit smaller, but still comfortable to read.

According to Your suggestion, I would have had to resize some hundred panels and the spaces between them, which would have been tedious and error-prone.

Comment: I preferred to change the Page setup, which was 3 clicks per document. But now, the point 0,0 was off, and it changed in every document. That was my issue...   (btw. the question was ~1 year old)

Comment: @user3240047: rather .5 years. i just came across your question searching for something else dia related. I can't tell you why dia was written the way it is, I'm afraid. But you could ask the mailing list ...

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issues when using pdf export in dia, and it is fixed by avoiding the pdf export, and to rather use a pdf printer instead.